# Using forEach to iterate an array, add to object and use the forEach index for the object key doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to iterate of an array using `forEach`, then add the values of that array to an object.

When adding to the object I want to be able to name the object keys with an increasing number, just like when using a normal `for loop` using the `i` variable counter.

With the code below:

```
var myArray = [123, 15, 187, 32];
var testObj = {}
myArray.forEach(function (value, i) {
    console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
    var objectKeyName = "item" + i; // ⬅️ here
    testObj.objectKeyName = value;
});
console.log(testObj);
```

I would expect `testObj` to be

```
{
    item0: 123,
    item1: 15,
    item2: 187,
    item3: 32, 
}
```

instead it outputs:

```
{objectKeyName: 32}
```

Why is this? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a variable as the property name. In that situation you cannot use dot notation, and must instead use bracket notation to access the object.

The reason you see only one item in the object currently is because you only set the `objectKeyName` property, and overwrite it in each iteration of the `forEach`.

```js
var myArray = [123, 15, 187, 32];
var testObj = {}
myArray.forEach(function(value, i) {
  var objectKeyName = "item" + i;
  testObj[objectKeyName] = value; // Note the [] surrounding the variable name here
});
console.log(testObj);
```

Comment: ahhh I see. So if you're adding/updating an object property value with a variable its bracket notation! Thanks dude! 

Comment: That's it exactly. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use `testObj[objectKeyName] = value` instead of `testObj.objectKeyName = value`.  The dot notation assigns the key value literally.

Comment: Thanks mate! that's great! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution

```js
var myArray = [123, 15, 187, 32];
var testObj = {}
myArray.forEach(function(value, i) {
  testObj["item" + i] = value;
});
console.log(testObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [123, 15, 187, 32];
var testObj = [];
myArray.forEach(function (value, i) {
    console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
    var objectKeyName = "item" + i; // ⬅️ here
    testObj.push(objectKeyName + ":" + value);
});
console.log(testObj);
testObj.forEach(function (value, i) {
    console.log(value);
});
```